# error with sudo and without sudo

Tags: 14.04, apt, sudo, azure

I have created an Ubuntu VM on Azure, but I have some  problem when I try to install a program. Command with `sudo` and without `sudo`:

```
ali@Azure:~$ sudo apt-get update
bash: sudo: command not found
ali@Azure:~$  apt-get update
W: chmod 0700 of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory
 (1: Operation not permitted)
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
ali@Azure:~$
```

Comment: run `which sudo`!

Comment: and run `type sudo su`

Comment: still doesn't work

sudo / sudo su / without sudo

Comment: solve, the problem was login as guest, not as admin. TY guys

Comment: You can answer this question, and mark it as accepted answer. It'll be fine.